# Нужен ли сервер для регистрации в приложении

Tags: сервер, регистрация

Я собираюсь сделать приложение! Но я хотел бы создать приложение чтобы там можно было зарегистрироваться. Но тут же вопрос нужен ли какой нибудь сервер для сохранения данных пользователей? Приложение мобильное!

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужен, данные пользователей нужно же где-то хранить, для этого и существуют базы данных.